# Updated Angular 9 to 9.1, getting error "This expression is not callable"

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, uuid

In my `package.json`, I updated Angular `^9.0.6` to `^9.1.1`

When I run `ng build`, I am getting the error:

```
"This expression is not callable." ...@types/uuid/index has no call signatures
```

The error occurs for the line where I call uuid(), see here:

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

public getUuid(): string {
    return uuid();
}
```

I tried with different versions of uuid `^3.4.0` to `^7.0.3`. When I downgrade Angular the error goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to change the import to this (v4 is the most popular according to the [uuid documentation](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#readme)):

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

**Explanation**: I looked in `node_modules\@types\uuid\interfaces.d.ts` and saw that there were exports for different versions (`v1` to `v5`). So after checking the documentation I opted for `v4`. It seems Angular 9.1 does not like the `import *` syntax in this case - have not been able to identify the reason yet.